# Control namespace prefixes in web services?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, xml-namespaces

My question is about the WS prefixes. When the services are deployed to different servers (Tomcat, WebLogic, WebSphere) generated prefixes are different (for instance tomcat has ns0 but WebLogic has ns1).
That fact disturbs me to test the services with the same test cases in SoapUI.
How can I overpass that or force the same prefix everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Namespace prefix names are insignificant; it is only through their binding to a namespace value that they derive meaning.   No conformant XML processor will care about the specific namespace prefix names; you should not either.

Comment: I understand that's insignificant but it still disturbs in my unit test where I hook a few operation together and the response of 1 action acts as an input to another. So when I expect <ns0:element ...  I would like to have exactly that and not for <ns1:element ... .Anyway I found the workaround or actually pretty slick solution by adding special annotation to package-info class generated from my XSD, it is enforcing the prefix I specify to be used rather than generated random one

Comment: Ideally your unit tests would not be sensitive to namespace prefixes either, but I'm glad you found a way forward that works for you.