# Replace prefixes in XML-message

Tags: xml, replace, pipeline, biztalk, prefix

BACKGROUND:

We have a send port that uses a XML Transmitt pipeline to output xml-files. These files have prefixes like <ns0: or <ns1: etc.
This makes it hard for the targetsystem to read these files, so we would like to replace prefixes <ns0: with <nl: and <ns1: with <cbc: and so on.
We can't change the source schema. We have to change the message outputed from the pipeline.

I wrote a custom XML-reader that takes a , separated string with the namespaces it should replace and puts them in a Dictionary. If a prefix exists
in the dictionary it is replaced.
Testing this reader with an earlier outputed message gives the expected results. But when I try to put it to use in a pipeline i run into problems.

APPROACH:

1. A pipeline with an XML-Assembler in Assemble stage and my custom reader in a component in the Decode stage, the idea was to take the message from the
   XML-Assembler and the modify it. Gives me an error stating:

"There was a failure executing the send pipeline: 
Reason: Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set
to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment."

But both my reader and writer in the Decode stage uses ConformanceLevel.Auto so I don't know how to solve that problem.

2. A pipeline with just my component in the Decode stage, this should work I think. It kind of does, but the XML looks a bit different and
   the biggest difference is that the root element and xmldeclaration is missing.

Here is the code for the pipeline component (NamespaceReplacements and OmitXmlDeclaration are properties):

```
public Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage Execute(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext pContext, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage pInMsg)
{
    IBaseMessagePart bodyPart = pInMsg.BodyPart;

    if (bodyPart != null)
    {
        Stream originalStream = bodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream();
        if (originalStream != null)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            readerSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;

            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlChangePrefixReader(XmlReader.Create(originalStream, readerSettings), NamespaceReplacements))
            {
                XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                writerSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;
                writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = OmitXmlDeclaration;

                MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

                using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputStream, writerSettings))
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartDocument();
                        reader.Read();
                    }

                    reader.Read();
                    while (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        writer.WriteNode(reader, true);
                    }
                }
                outputStream.Position = 0;
                bodyPart.Data = outputStream;
            }
        }
    }
    return pInMsg;
}
```

And here is the code for the reader:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

public class XmlChangePrefixReader : XmlReader
{
    private XmlReader _wrappedReader;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _prefixReplacements;

    //Private to hide default constructor
    private XmlChangePrefixReader()
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wrappedReader">Internal xmlreader</param>
    /// <param name="prefixReplacements">Prefixes to be replaced in a , separated string. Ex "A;B;C;D" will replace A with B and C with D.</param>
    public XmlChangePrefixReader(XmlReader wrappedReader, string prefixReplacements)
    {
        Initialise(wrappedReader, prefixReplacements);
    }

    #region Untouched overrides

    public override int AttributeCount { get { return _wrappedReader.AttributeCount; } }
    public override string BaseURI { get { return _wrappedReader.BaseURI; } }
    public override void Close() { _wrappedReader.Close(); }
    public override int Depth { get { return _wrappedReader.Depth; } }
    public override bool EOF { get { return _wrappedReader.EOF; } }
    public override string GetAttribute(int i) { return _wrappedReader.GetAttribute(i); }
    public override string GetAttribute(string name, string namespaceURI) { return _wrappedReader.GetAttribute(name, namespaceURI); }
    public override string GetAttribute(string name) { return GetAttribute(name); }
    public override bool HasValue { get { return _wrappedReader.HasValue; } }
    public override bool IsEmptyElement { get { return _wrappedReader.IsEmptyElement; } }
    public override string LookupNamespace(string prefix) { return _wrappedReader.LookupNamespace(prefix); }
    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name, string ns) { return _wrappedReader.MoveToAttribute(name, ns); }
    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name) { return _wrappedReader.MoveToAttribute(name); }
    public override bool MoveToElement() { return _wrappedReader.MoveToElement(); }
    public override bool MoveToFirstAttribute() { return _wrappedReader.MoveToFirstAttribute(); }
    public override bool MoveToNextAttribute() { return _wrappedReader.MoveToNextAttribute(); }
    public override XmlNameTable NameTable { get { return _wrappedReader.NameTable; } }
    public override string NamespaceURI { get { return _wrappedReader.NamespaceURI; } }
    public override XmlNodeType NodeType { get { return _wrappedReader.NodeType; } }
    public override bool Read() { return _wrappedReader.Read(); }
    public override bool ReadAttributeValue() { return _wrappedReader.ReadAttributeValue(); }
    public override ReadState ReadState { get { return _wrappedReader.ReadState; } }
    public override void ResolveEntity() { _wrappedReader.ResolveEntity(); }
    public override string Value { get { return _wrappedReader.Value; } }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes localname if it contains a prefix that should be changed
    /// </summary>
    public override string LocalName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_prefixReplacements.ContainsKey(_wrappedReader.LocalName))
                return _prefixReplacements[_wrappedReader.LocalName];
            else
                return _wrappedReader.LocalName;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Changes prefix if it is a prefix that should be changed
    /// </summary>
    public override string Prefix
    {
        get
        {
            if (_prefixReplacements.ContainsKey(_wrappedReader.Prefix))
                return _prefixReplacements[_wrappedReader.Prefix];
            else
                return _wrappedReader.Prefix;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wrappedReader">Internal xmlreader</param>
    /// <param name="prefixReplacements">Prefixes to be replaced</param>
    private void Initialise(XmlReader wrappedReader, string prefixReplacements)
    {
        if (wrappedReader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("XmlChangePrefixReader: wrappedReader is null");

        _wrappedReader = wrappedReader;

        _prefixReplacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (prefixReplacements != null)
        {
            var prefixArray = prefixReplacements.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < prefixArray.Length; i = i + 2)
            {
                _prefixReplacements.Add(prefixArray[i], prefixArray[i + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how I can get approac 1 or 2 to work? Or should I try another approach?

Comment: It is better to remove XML namespaces and their prefixes by using XSLT.

Answer (score 3):

### Namespace prefixes alone are insignificant

Your efforts are proving difficult because your goal is misguided.  Namespace prefixes alone are insignificant.  **It's only through their binding to namespace values that namespace prefixes derive  significance.**

Against this foundation, you are trying to treat namespace prefixes as if they actually matter apart from their bound namespace values.  They do not.  You are therefore not going to have an easy time fighting conformant libraries that properly treat namespace prefixes alone as being insignificant.

Those given this message usually react in one of two ways:

1. Angrily, because they just want a quick fix to eliminate an inherited problem as they perceive it.
2. Happily, because they now feel justified in fixing the underlying problem, or pointing a customer/client/boss/colleague to a source that confirms that it is the downstream system that is broken in requiring specific namespace prefixes.

#2 is strongly recommended: Fix the underlying problem – don't perpetuate it via a hack.

### See also

- [Does having a different name for the XML namespace prefix matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54791081/290085)
- [Namespace in XML element value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38745861/290085)
- [Control namespace prefixes in web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32076532/290085)
- [XmlObject.selectPath() is generating the wrong Namespace prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42650046/290085)
- [Excel to XML Namespace Prefix Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38463769/290085)
- Etc.

Comment: Then I choose 1.. but only slightly. As I stated in my question 
"We can't change the source schema"

How are we then to fix the problem, the system that reads these files does not work properly when it gets <ns1 or something similar...

Why does BizTalk generate his <ns0 tags? But maybe that is another question...

Comment: Not being able to "change the source schema" is irrelevant: An XML Schema simply cannot dictate namespace prefixes.  This is consistent with the point being made here that XML namespace prefixes matter only through their binding to XML namespace values.

Comment: The point is the target system can not read our files with the <ns0: prefixes. They need to be fixed. So for us the prefixes and namespaces matter.

Comment: I agree with kjhughes, this is the correct answer, but sometimes you can't choose your target system... Let them know that they have this problem (some senior developer must check it). I'd present a fix for this, in the Decode stage, just do a custom pipeline component to replace the prefixes in the resulting xml by using textreader/-writer, controlled by configuration, including Enabled property for you to disable it once the system have corrected their "bug".

Comment: I am using a custom reader as stated in my question, but it doesn't work and the idea is to have it in a custom pipeline. If the target system fixes its problem I can simply switch to an ordinary XML Transmit on my send port.
I'm all for fixin the root cause but sometimes the complexity of a system or chain prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic XSLT to remove namespaces from an XML.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <!-- template to copy elements -->
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- template to copy attributes -->
   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
   <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: But I don't want to remove them, I want to change the prefixes. we have a component that removes namespaces if we want to.

One advantage with a pipeline is that I can have properties on it, so I can change which prefixes I want to replace if necessary